# how to write a dataframe from scala to HDFS as csv

Tags: scala

I am new to scala and HDFS. I need to dump my data into HDFS. The data is in the form of a spark dataframe but I want to write it as a CSV in HDFS.
Can someone please share the basic boilder plate code for starters.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, we don't write code for you without an [mcve] from you first. What have you tried?. - [From Review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/12773502)

Answer (score 1):

If your data is flat then the following would work.

```
val df: DataFrame = ???
val filePath: String = ???
df.map(_.mkString(",")).saveAsTextFile(filePath)
```

However the issue with the question is that we need to see what your data looks like. For example if its got nested Structs then saving as a CSV isn't clearly defined.

Comment: I have written my dataframe as csv into a single csv file on local disk but I want to write this into hdfs.
userJourneyDf.repartition(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save("C:/AI/Hive/userJourneyDf2")
        val dir = new File("C:/AI/Hive/userJourneyDf2")
    val tmpTsvFile = "C:/AI/Hive/userJourneyDf2" + File.separatorChar + "part-00000"
    (new File(tmpTsvFile)).renameTo(new File("C:/AI/Hive/userJourneyDf3.csv"))
    dir.listFiles.foreach( f => f.delete )
    dir.delete

Comment: Perhaps this would be better asked as a separate question with more detail provided?